# How to transfer an objective with separate positive and negative parts into linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, linearization

I've got to deal with an optimization problem as follows,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\max_{x,y} & a^Tx+y^TKx\\
{s.t.}&Ax=b\\
&{Cx}\leq d\\
l&\leq y\leq u\end{aligned}
$$
where $x \in \bf{R}^n$, $y \in \bf{R}^m$. An intuitive is that as $y$ is bounded in $[l,u]$, the later term in the objective ($y^TKx$) can be rewritten as
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{m}\{\max\{(Kx)_j,0\}u_j+\min\{(Kx)_j,0\}l_j\}
$$
How can I incorporate the above expression in the optimization problem to avoid bilinear term?

Comment: Are you willing to introduce binary variables and solve a mixed integer linear program?

Comment: @prubin Sure. Can you tell me how to do?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that $\ell \ge 0.$ We introduce nonnegative variables $0\le w,z \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and binary variables $v\in \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace^m$ and convert the objective to maximizing $a^T x + u^T w - \ell^T z.$ We also add the following constraints, where $M_j$ is a valid upper bound on $\vert (Kx)_j \vert:$
$$Kx - w + z = 0$$
$$w_j \le M_j v_j \quad\forall j$$
$$z_j \le M_j (1-v_j) \quad \forall j.$$

Comment: Dear @prubin, why not try to just set $y$ in its upper bound? As the problem is of the form maximization, the value of the variable $y$ will take its upper bound. Otherwise, if the domain of the variable $y$ was not unbounded, the problem may be unbounded.

Comment: @A.Omidi Suppose that $(Kx)_j < 0.$ If you set $y_j = u_j,$ you *reduce* the objective by the largest amount possible.

Comment: Dear @prubin, thanks. I actually supposed the variable $x \geq 0$. 

Comment: @A.Omidi $x\ge 0$ might well be intended, but the key is whether $Kx \ge 0,$ and I see no reason to assume that.

Comment: @prubin Thank you. I also want to ask is the original problem equivalent to the folloing formulation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\max_{x,y} & a^Tx+1^Tt\\
{s.t.}&Ax=b\\
&{Cx}\leq d\\
&Kx - w + z = 0\\
& w_j l_j-z_j u_j \leq t_j \leq w_j u_j - z_jl_j\\ 
& 0 \leq w_j, z_j \leq M_j
\end{aligned}
$$
where $M_j$ is a big M number.

Comment: @KaimingZhang No, that is not an equivalent formulation, because it allows both $w_j$ and $z_j$ to be positive simultaneously. That allows the value of the second objective term to become inflated.

Comment: @prubin If the variable $x$ is confined in a cone $K$, the transformed problem becomes a conic programming problem with binary variables. Is it easy to solve with off-the-shelf solvers?

Comment: Sorry, conic problems are not my forte.